# changing report viewer display value in expression

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report, reportviewer

I am using visual studio report viewer and to display bolean type column.It displays true or false for each row. Instead of true i want to display "Approved" . how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your database query and use `IF-ELSE` condition like

```
select case when columnname = 'true' Then  'Approved' else 'Rejected' end as Status from tablename
```

You have to make your database query something like that.

Hope you understand and works for you.